# window.location in IE base href

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, relative-path

I'm having an issue with Internet Explorer and the window.location.

I'm using Backbone.js for my backend project.

The base URL is 'http://www.domain.com/admin/'

And my js function looks like :

```
openFolder : function(e) {
        var folder_id = '4';
        window.location = "controller/folder/" + folder_id;
    },
```

So when I'm on the page 'www.domain.com/admin/controller' and I click on a button to open folder, it work well on all browser except for Internet Explorer that redirect me to
'http://www.domain.com/admin/controller/controller/folder/4'

Can you help me with this issue ?

Thank you
Ilan

Comment: Try window.location.assign("controller/folder/" + folder_id);

Comment: Not working with IE and also now with Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

```
location.href = location.origin + "/controller/folder/" + folder_id;
```

Comment: Tried it and it redirect me in all browser to www.domain.com/controller/folder/4 instead of www.domain.com/admin/controller/folder/4

Comment: Of course, `location.href = location.origin + "/admin/controller/folder/" + folder_id;`

Comment: Yeah I know but the problem is that if tomorrow I put the backend under a subdomain as 'http://admin.domain.com/', I'll need to change all my js code and it's not very good :/

Comment: You may store basic location as a constant: `var BASE = location.origin + '/admin';`, so you won't need to change all your js code, you'll need only to change one variable.